# Two average with one group by in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, database, group-by

I have two group by and average queries, i need to get both result together. I mean assume i have two queries like this:

```
select timespan, count(*) c1
from dbo 
where C > 50
group by timespan
having count(*) > 100
```

and

```
select timespan, count(*) c2
from dbo 
where C < 50
group by timespan
having count(*) > 130
```

***EDITED** I need to have both next to each other*

```
  TimeSpan, c1, c2
    630,  120, 100
    631,  140, 120
```

This is my query in SQL Server, but it doesn't work:

```
select 
    gt, ls 
from  
    (select count (*) gt 
     from dbo.Alltrips 
     where DrivingTime > 50  
       and CarId in (select CarId from dbo.Alltrips 
                     group by CarId 
                     having Count (*) > 100) 
     group by timeSpan) a,
    (select count (*) ls 
     from dbo.Alltrips 
     where DrivingTime < 50  
       and CarId in (select CarId from dbo.Alltrips 
                     group by CarId 
                     having Count (*) > 130) 
     group by timeSpan) b
```

Comment: I'm struggling to understand exactly what result you're looking for. Your actual query is *not* the same as the first two that you say you want to get the results from at the same time. Could you perhaps explain in words the result you are trying to get?

Comment: my finaly big query is wrong , I need to concatenate two first queries but with only one timespan. I Edited my desired sample, please take a look. thanks

Comment: I understand the first part. But in your sample query you have the `having count(*) > 100` applied to the outer query, but in your actual query you have it on a subquery. Without knowing exactly what you're trying to achieve it's not possible to know what is correct. It looks (from your actual query) like you're trying to count the number of cars that did more than 100 trips overall and had a trip with more than 50 drivingtime in a given timespan?

Comment: the two first queries are right queries which i want their results be concatenated, you simply ignore the last big query. "count the number of cars that did more than 100 trips overall" WHERE C>50 it is the first part ,c1. the second part is similar which has count(*) c2 .

Answer (score 1):

Use conditional aggregation:

```sql
SELECT timespan,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN C > 100 THEN 1 END) AS C1,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN C > 130 THEN 1 END) AS C2
FROM dbo.dbo --Do you really have a table called dbo?
GROUP BY timespan
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN C > 100 THEN 1 END) > 100;
```

Comment: I think my numbers are confusing, I edited. And no dbo is just a hypothetical name, :) . thanks

Comment: Then change the numbers for what you need @Azzurro94 . I based the answer on your original version, however, it's simple to change a literal integer.

Comment: i don't understand why you are just checking this on Having, HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN C > 100 THEN 1 END) > 100; and I changed the numbers as well.

Comment: Because for your original the latter would have been true, @Azzurro94 . You moved the goal posts, but I haven't changed the answer; though it shows you the principle still, use conditional aggregation. You'll want an `OR` now, most likely.